# X11 keycode vs keyboard mapping

Tags: keyboard, x11, keyboard-events

I use Ubuntu 20.04 and QWERTY US layout. I have created a X11 application. When I press 'y' on the keyboard I get `KeyPress` event and `XKeyEvent` structure contains `keycode` '29'. I have always thought that a key code value depends on the current keyboard layout but when I change the keyboard layout to QWERTZ (German) I still get the key code with the value '29' when I press 'y' key. Does it mean that a key code represent the physical key location on the keyboard and it's value is independent from the keyboard layout ?

Comment: That's right, keycodes are independent from the keyboard layout.